# Multi-select not working with crmUiSelect AngularJS select2 directive

Tags: developer, angular, select2

I created a select2 element with CiviCRM's `crmUiSelect` AngularJS directive by using the following code in my controller:

```
$scope.options = [
  {"value": "foo", "label": "Foo"},
  {"value": "bar", "label": "Bar"},
  {"value": "baz", "label": "Baz"},
  {"value": "bat", "label": "Bat"}
];
```

and the following code in my template:

```
<select
  crm-ui-select="{allowClear: true}"
  ng-model="myVar"
  ng-options="option as option.label for option in options track by option.value"
  multiple="multiple"
  class="big"
>
</select>

{{myVar}}
```

It sort of worked, but here's what I ended up with:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the above screenshot, this element has the following problems:

- `myVar` is an array with only *one* element, even when multiple options are selected.
- The list of options contains options which have already been selected (and the element actually allows these options to be selected more than once).

How can I fix this element so that it works as expected? I want `myVar` to become `["foo", "bar"]` in the screenshot above, and I want the user to only see options which have not already been selected.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you can't use the `ngOptions` directive with select2 multi-select elements. You need to manually specify the `<option>` elements with `ngRepeat` like this instead:

```
<select
  crm-ui-select="{allowClear: true}"
  ng-model="myVar"
  multiple="multiple"
  class="big"
>
  <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}">
    {{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>

{{myVar}}
```

That produces the desired behavior:

[image: screenshot]